# Why CSS.supports() is failing when running it with jest

Tags: javascript, css, jestjs, jsdom

I am trying to run a test that has `CSS.supports()` function in it.

```
describe('something', () => {
    it('fails',() => {
        CSS.supports('display', 'flex');
    } )
})
```

I get this error: `ReferenceError: CSS is not defined`.

Shouldn't JSDOM support this function?
Thanks!

Comment: Add the code please.

Comment: Edited my question and added the code.

Comment: This is not implemented yet in JSDom. Found this answer here:
https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/2026

Answer (score 2):

This is not implemented in JSDom, but you can code around it by checking if `CSS.supports` exists and then the tests won't fail like so:

```
const supportsDvh = CSS.supports && CSS.supports('height: 100dvh');
```